# react-native icons does not show

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm web enginneer in Japan and I'm studying react-native.

I finished react-native tutorial [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content)

And learn create tab [here](http://devdactic.com/react-native-tab-bar/)

But featuread tab and search tab not show...

I don't know why this...

please help me.

Thank you for your patient with my poor English.

This is my codes.

【index.ios.js】

```
    'use strict';

    var React = require('react-native');
    var Featured = require('./Featured');
    var Search = require('./Search');

    var {
        AppRegistry,
        TabBarIOS,
        Component
       } = React;

    class Qiita_Reader extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          selectedTab: 'featured'
        };
      }

      render() {
      return (
        <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
          <TabBarIOS.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
            icon={{uri:'Featured'}}
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'featured'
                });
            }}>
           <Featured/>
           </TabBarIOS.Item>
             <TabBarIOS.Item
               selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'search'}
               icon={{uri:'search'}}
               onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedTab: 'search'
                    });
                }}>
                <Search/>
              </TabBarIOS.Item>
          </TabBarIOS>
        );
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('qiita_reader', () => Qiita_Reader);
```

【Featured.js】

```
    'use strict';

    var React = require('react-native');

    var {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
    } = React;

    var FeaturedTab = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>This is Featured Tab !!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    });

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      description: {
        fontSize: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    });

    module.exports = FeaturedTab;
```

【Search.js】

```
    'use strict';

    var React = require('react-native');

    var {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
    } = React;

    var SearchTab = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>This is SearchTab !!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    });

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      description: {
        fontSize: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
      }
    });

    module.exports = SearchTab;
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the code you are using for the tab bar?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I see the problem now.  Check the [docs for the TabBarIOS.Item Component.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios-item.html#content)  The **icon** property that you are using is only for custom icons that you upload into XCode.  If you want to use the system icons, including the ones for search and featured, you want to use the **systemIcon** prop, followed by the lower-case name of the icon.

It should be

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
        icon="featured"
```

and

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'search'}
        icon="search"
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I did it. 
But I can't see icons.

Comment: Just updated my answer, try it out and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!
I adopted that code! and use option 'systemIcon'.
I worked! Thanksssss!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **systemIcon** instead of **icon**

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
  selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
  systemIcon='featured'>
</TabBarIOS.Item>
<TabBarIOS.Item
  selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
  systemIcon='featured'>
</TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Comment: I think this solution is much better than the one which the asker chose. This code works very well in my case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a static image you can also use this code:

```
icon={require('./myimage.png')}
```